# .net split command acting strange

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split

I have these two code lines :

```
Dim templine() = Alfalines(i).Split(DataGridView1.Rows(s).Cells(1).Value)  
textlines(i) = Alfaline(0) + DataGridView1.Rows(s).Cells(language_row).Value + Alfaline(1)
```

`DataGridView1.Rows(s).Cells(1).Value` from the first line has the value `"Form2A186_1"` and `Alfalines(i)` at the moment of the error :**"       Caption         =  "Form2A186_1"**

The problem is that split command recognize as delimeter the F and it splits the String to:

```
0: "Caption    =   "    
1: "orm2A186_1"
```

Comment: What is your setting for OPTION STRICT? ON or OFF, I presume OFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that String.Split() method with on argument only takes char[] as its parameter, not string, or string[], as per documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

So in order to split by string, you should use this overload:

```
Public Function Split ( _
    separator As String(), _
    options As StringSplitOptions _
) As String()
```

Comment: MyString.Split(new String() {MySeparator},StringSplitOptions.None)